# How to pass a function as a parameter to a function macro in C++

Tags: c++

I'm following a C++ tutorial from here -  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/ to learn about **Preprocessor directives**.

So, I tried to write a simple function macro that would accept a function name as a parameter and define the function but I don't seem to find any example on how to do so.

My attempt is as below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define FUNCTION_WRAPPER(function) function(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }

FUNCTION_WRAPPER(multiply);

int main() {
    multiply(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.

Comment: Well it would compile if you changed it to this `#define FUNCTION_WRAPPER(function) void function(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }

FUNCTION_WRAPPER(multiply)` but I really have no idea what you are trying to do here. This macro takes a function name as a parameter, not a function.

Comment: If you're writing C++ you should ignore macros as good as you can; there are __very few__ reasons to use macros in C++.

Comment: You forgot the `void` before function in your macro. However, I recommand you to not use macro or only in a few cases

Comment: Try to stay away from macros.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments! Thanks to you I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are simple textual replacements and you can get most compiler suites to treat them as such and give you the actual textual expansion.

The POSIX-standardized `-E` option to C compilers effectively does that (without it, preprocessing usually happens at the token level (not textually), which is basically a micro-optimization compared to textual preprocessing). gcc and clang in C++ mode have the `-E` option as well.

Considering this, the best way to learn about the preprocessor, in my opinion, is to open a source file in one window and a watch program that interactively preprocesses the file in another.

file.cc:

```
#define FUNCTION_WRAPPER(function) function(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }
FUNCTION_WRAPPER(multiply)
```

terminal:

```
 watch -n 0.2 gcc -E file.cc
```

The above should give you the following preprocessor output:

```
multiply(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }
```

From it, it should be obvious you're missing a return value in the function definition.

Fix:

```
#define FUNCTION_WRAPPER(function) void function(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }
FUNCTION_WRAPPER(multiply)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the type of the function:

```
#define FUNCTION_WRAPPER(function) \
    void function(int arg1, int arg2) { cout << arg1 * arg2; }
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul. I am on phone and I didn't find 'code' style for text format.